# Application of Laplace transform to stopping times and expectations

Tags: probability, probability-theory, laplace-transform, martingales, stopping-times

Let $X_k$ be i.i.d. random variables such that $E[X_1]=m<\infty$. Consider $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k$. Let $\tau$ be a stopping time independent of $X_k$ with respect to the filtration $\{F_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ generated by the random variables $X_k$, $(k=1,2,...,n)$. Compute $E[e^{\sum_{k=1}^{\tau} X_k}]$. My professor gave me a hint: Compute the Laplace transform $E[e^{-u S_{\tau}}], u>0$.

** I am looking for constructive hints. I don't know how to start. **

What I am thinking:
Let $g(s) = E[e^{-sX_1}],s>0$ and $f(z) = E[z^{\tau}], |z| \leq 1$.

Comment: It would seem to me that $$\mathbb E[e^{\sum_{k=1}^\tau}] = \mathbb E\left[\prod_{k=1}^\tau e^{X_k}\right] = \mathbb E[\tau]\mathbb E[e^{X_1}] $$ though I'm not sure how to prove this.

Comment: @Math1000 Are you saying to do this: $$E[\prod_{k=1}^{\tau} e^{X_k} ]= \sum_{l=1}^{\infty} P(\tau = l) E[\prod_{k=1}^{l} e^{X_k} ] = \sum_{l=1}^{\infty} P(\tau = l) E[e^{X_k}]^l$$

Comment: @Math1000 I believe your statement would be true if we were trying to compute $E[\sum_{k=1}^{\tau}]$. That is called Wald's identity I believe.

Comment: Yes, that was my inspiration. There is a generalization of Wald's identity involving moment generating functions though: http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~peledron/Teaching/RW_and_BM_2011/scribe2.pdf

Comment: @Math1000 I am having trouble understanding the connection to the Laplace transform here.